# Reduce shape of tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow

So I am creating a tensorflow model but it uses an existing model whose output has a shape of [1, 512] or something like that.
I want to add a couple of layers to it at the end but it needs to end up with the same output shape as the number of classes which is something much smaller

[1, 5] for example.

What is the best way to reduce the output so it matches without losing too much data?

I tried pooling but I don't think I understand it enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the output to a dense layer like: `logits = tf.layers.dense(outputs, units=5)` to reduce from `512` to `5` output units.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!